# Getting QueryDSL JAR files without Maven

Tags: java, querydsl, sqlbuilder

Please excuse a newbie such as I for this silly question. 
I am trying to install QueryDSL in my Java project in Eclipse Mars to use it for SQL querying. I do not use Maven yet, and don't know how to use it, though it's definitely on my to learn list.

The [QueryDSL page](http://www.querydsl.com/) points to their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl), but it's not clear to me how to add it to my project. Please advise on how can I get the full list of JAR files to add to my Eclipse Java project, without using Maven.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to querydsl.com and click "Downloads" under "Documentation".